# objects dynamic casting downcasting

Tags: c++, pointers, object

- I want to ask about this line, is a **downcast from object_ptr to ptr**?
- This is because **an object_ptr is NOT a ptr** and we need to downcasting?

  ```
  MyClass * ptr = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(object_ptr);
  ```

Comment: We need an [mcve] in be order to be able to tell you.

Comment: What is `object_ptr`? What is your real problem? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NathanOliver the question is general, and it's about this line and the use of this cast, thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry man i try to ask good questions

Comment: Which one is base class and which one is derived? To answer your question we need that information

Comment: @Asesh we take this as a true condition, so i think the object_ptr is an object of base class and MyClass is the derived.

Comment: @tonerognwrizei: When you say that you try to ask good questions, I'll give you the benefit of doubt for that. However, as it stands, it *is not* a good question. You are encouraged to have a look at the MCVE link given to you, and to formulate questions which are actually questions, because I have no idea what your problem is and what you are asking.

Comment: @ChristianHackl ok sorry, i am asking for the use of dynamic cast here. That's the question. I ll read the MCVE link

Comment: @tonerognwrizei: I know that you are asking something which has to do with `dynamic_cast`; that much is obvious. But "use of dynamic cast" does not make a question. A question would be something like "Why does the compiler not allow this cast?" or "Why does this cast work fine even if object_ptr should not allow that because [...]?"

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> MyClass * ptr = dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(object_ptr);
> ```
>
> is a downcast from object_ptr to ptr?

It is a cast from the type of `object_ptr` into `MyClass*`. The variable `ptr` is copy-initialized from the result of the conversion. The quoted code does perform a downcast if and only if `object_ptr` is a pointer to a base of `MyClass`.

> This is because an object_ptr is NOT a ptr and we need to downcasting?

`object_ptr` and `ptr` are variables. A variable is not another variable, but that has nothing to do with downcasting.